# re-render component when Moment() changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making a calendar with `moment()` but I got a problem with this.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Calendar = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(moment());
  function handleClick(date){
    console.log('handleClick called', date);
    setValue(date);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=> handleClick(value.add(-1,'month')) }> - </button>
      <b>{ value.format('YYYY-MM') } </b>
      <button onClick={()=> handleClick(value.add(1,'month')) }> + </button>

    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => (<Calendar />)
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

when I click the button, the property is updated obviously, but re-rendering doesn't occur.

I can guess it is about `shallow compare` but I have no idea what is the most proper way to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead mutating the value keep a shadow variable and the setValue, I think mutation is preventing the rerender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `clone` to create a new moment instance instead of changing initial one.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Calendar = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(moment());
  function handleClick(date){
    console.log('handleClick called', date);
    setValue(date);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=> handleClick(value.clone().add(-1,'month')) }> - </button>
      <b>{ value.format('YYYY-MM') } </b>
      <button onClick={()=> handleClick(value.clone().add(1,'month')) }> + </button>

    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => (<Calendar />)
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Great answer. :)